# Running composer install and then copying project files in a docker project

Tags: docker, composer-php, dockerfile

Trying to understand this bit of Dockerfile that I found in a PHP project.

```
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
RUN set -eux; \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest; \
    composer clear-cache

COPY . ./
```

Lines 1 and 2 copy composer definition files and run composer install, so far so good.

But immediately it would seem that all the project files (which would include the aforementioned composer definition files) are copied to the same destination.

What is gained by not running the `composer install` **after** the. `COPY . ./` step? If on the host `composer install` had already ran, woudn't that overwrite the work done in the first two lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take advantage of docker's cache when you try to build the docker image again.
Let's say you have this:

```
COPY . ./

RUN set -eux; \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest; \
    composer clear-cache
```

This is fine, and the end result will be the same. The difference is that if you change any file in your repository, then all the instruction from the `COPY` will ran again. This mean that if you change anything ( maybe you added an image, or change a css file, or deleted a php file), you will re-install all the dependencies, even if you don't really need to. And the `composer install` will take its (long) time as well. Time that you can save.

Now take your example:

```
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
RUN set -eux; \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest; \
    composer clear-cache

COPY . ./
```

Now the only time you need to install again your packages, is when `composer.json` or `composer.lock` changes. You don't trigger it every time.

Comment: Seems really dumb and obvious when explained down. But couldn't really see it until now. :( The only remaining doubt is the second part of my question: if `composer install` had already ran on the host, wouldn't that overwrite the result of the first step? Seems a bit messy.

Comment: You mean, you have a `vendor` folder on your host machine, and with `COPY . ./` you copy it on the docker image, overwriting the previous `composer install`? Usually you have a `.dockerignore` with the `vendor` folder in it to prevent this